# jQuery: How can I show an image popup onclick of the thumbnail?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, popup

In my aspx page I have a thumbnail image `<img>`. When the user clicks on that image I would like a popup to show that blocks out the rest of the UI with the larger (full) version of the image.

Are there any plugins that can do this?

Comment: you mean something like this? http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Answer (score 113, accepted):

There are a lot of jQuery plugins available for this

**[Thickbox](http://codylindley.com/thickbox/)**

**[LightBox](http://www.lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/?u=9)**

**[FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/)**

**[FaceBox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox)**

**[NyroModal](http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/)**

**[PiroBox](http://www.pirolab.it/pirobox/)**

***Thickbox Examples***

For a single image

> 1. Create a link element ()
> 2. Give the link a class attribute with a value of thickbox
>      (class="thickbox")
> 3. Provide a path in the href attribute to an image file (.jpg .jpeg
>      .png .gif .bmp)

Comment: i'd want my photo in ThickBox
i want code of image how 'd it look with link- img

Comment: See the examples section in the Thickbox site.

Comment: Might as well save a few of you a few minutes. Thickbox seems really buggy. It stops working when I inspect an element on the demo page in Chrome and it doesn't work for me on my own page even when I use the demo exactly.

Comment: hi , is there any wp plugin which shows poup up of all content area images on click. i used easy popup it is working fine but popup show in bottom of page if you gyz have any other please share link. thanks

Answer (score 8):

I like **[prettyPhoto](http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/)**

> prettyPhoto is a jQuery [lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/) clone. Not only does it support images, it also support for videos, flash, YouTube, iframes and ajax. It’s a full blown media lightbox

Answer (score 6):

This is the most popular (9500 stars) and light weight (20KB minify, 7.5KB minify+gzip) popup gallery I think:
[Magnific-Popup](https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/)

Answer (score 4):

I was in the same situation and found this one,

[WOWslider](http://wowslider.com/)

Answer (score 0):

prettyPhoto is a jQuery lightbox clone. Not only does it support images, it also support for videos, flash, YouTube, iframes and ajax. It’s a full blown media lightbox