# Javascript / css photo pop-up feature placement issues

Tags: javascript, css, magento, photo

I've used this site many times to find answers to my questions, but I can't seem to find an answer to my current issue. Any help would be great!

I'm using a custom photo pop-up feature add-on in Magento called TopUp. I contacted the original writer of the code and have not received a response. I Googled the issue and other users with Magento 1.6 and 1.7 are having the same issue.

When you click on a product image when viewing a product details page, the image should popup in the middle of the screen. Well, right now, the image pops up toward the bottom of the screen and when you click next or back, it re-positions itself further down.

Here's an exact link to a product where this applies (development site):
http://www.childress-media.com/shapingheartsforgod.org/index.php/shaping-hearts-series/pre-k-through-5th-grade/all-things-made-new/all-things-made-new-student-workbook-level-1.html

Here's the link to the Javascript pop-up program:
http://www.childress-media.com/shapingheartsforgod.org/skin/frontend/base/default/js/top_up/top_up-min.js

I've tried messing around with the CSS here and there within the file - but I can't make it do what I want.

Ideally, the pop-up would appear 100px from the top of the page and be centered and stay centered when you press next or previous.

Any help you guys can provide would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063199/jquery-how-can-i-show-an-image-popup-onclick-of-the-thumbnail

Answer (score 0):

An easy, but raw way to do this is setting a css style, like:

```
document.getElementById('top_up').style.top = '100px';
```

Comment: Where exactly would I put this?

Comment: I don't know exactly because I don't work with Magento, but you just have to execute this code after Magento creates and shows the TopUp window