# image popup with p:graphicImage

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a simple jsf primefaces code using a `p:graphicImage`

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{imageStreamer.image}" >
    <f:param name="id" value="#{item}" />
</p:graphicImage>
```

I am trying to add an "on click image pop up" function. I saw a list of [image pop-up using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063199/jquery-how-can-I-show-an-image-popup-onclick-of-the-thumbnail)

I have decided to use fancyBox, but I have no idea how to use it with primefaces graphicImage. Anyone can help?

it does not have to be fancyBox or any other jquery plugins. I just need a simple "on click image pop up" function.

**UPDATE**

tried using `Lightbox` but it does not work

```
<p:galleria id="photo-galleria" value="#{testController.ImageIdsView(list[1])}" var="item" autoPlay="false" frameWidth="200" frameHeight="188" panelWidth="625">  
    <p:lightBox styleClass="imagebox">  
        <h:outputLink value="#{imageStreamer.image}">  
            <p:graphicImage value="#{imageStreamer.image}" >
                <f:param name="id" value="#{item}" />
            </p:graphicImage>
        </h:outputLink>
    </p:lightBox>
</p:galleria>
```

the images gives me a broken link.

Note: without the `lightbox`, everything works fine.

Comment: I even come across the problem for combining `p:galleria` and `p:lightbox`. You need to modify the `galleria.js` file. It´s very simple! Just look for the lines where the image is fetched. With lightbox and and a link before the graphicImage the html is rendered differently. The galleria component assumes, that the image is directly under the li tag. With lightbox and outputlink there´s additionally a div and an a tag. So change `children('img')` to `.children('div').children('a').children('img')`...

Answer (score 0):

PrimeFaces has something for that. It's called LightBox.

See the [Showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/lightBox.jsf) here for an example.

Comment: I actually tried this before but it does not work for me. I updated my question for you to see on what I did.

Comment: Well, that won't work this way. You cannot combine galleria and lightbox. Use a <c:forEach> from JSTL inside the <p:lightBox> and generate your outputLinks with the pictures that way.

Just like it was done in the showcase, but dynamically via forEach.