# Show large image when click on small image

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am trying to show a large image when clicking on a small image. I have a SQL table in which I store the image, then I display this image in an img control. Now I want this image to open in a bigger size popup, when the user clicks on it.

My code to the retrieve the image from the database and display it in img control is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#image1Large').hide().click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
    });

    $('#image1').click(function() {
        $('#image1Large').attr('src', this.src)
            .show()
            .offset({ top: 0, left: 0 });
    });
</script>

<img  runat="server" id="image1" alt="" src="" height="100" width="100"/>
<img  runat="server" id="image1Large" alt=""/>

protected void LoadImage1()
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sps_getimage", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@flag", 1);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ad_id", ad_id);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SequentialAccess);
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        reader.Read();
        MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream();
        long startIndex = 0;
        const int ChunkSize = 256;
        while (true)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[ChunkSize];
            long retrievedBytes = reader.GetBytes(0, startIndex, buffer, 0, ChunkSize);
            memory.Write(buffer, 0, (int)retrievedBytes);
            startIndex += retrievedBytes;
            if (retrievedBytes != ChunkSize)
                break;
        }

        byte[] data = memory.ToArray();
        img1 = data;
        memory.Dispose();
        image1.Src = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(data);
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: Where is the JQuery Code?

Comment: @raj this link may useful to you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063199/jquery-how-can-i-show-an-image-popup-onclick-of-the-thumbnail

Comment: i think this is not gonna work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't really a C# or SQL problem, but rather client-side. Since you already retrieved the image and only resizing it via `height="100" width="100"` attributes, all you have to do is display the same image in its original size. There're many ways to do this, here is a basic one:

Add another image element to hold larger image:

```
<img  runat="server" id="image1" alt="" src="" height="100" width="100"/>
<img  runat="server" id="image1Large" />
```

And add this code to initially hide the larger image and show it on click:

```
$('#image1Large').hide().click(function(){
   $(this).hide();    
})


$('#image1').click(function(){
    $('#image1Large').attr('src', this.src)
                     .show()
                     .offset({top:0,left:0});    
})
```

**Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/QH5a8/**

In a real-life scenario, you will need to adjust this (perhaps additional formatting and positioning of larger image, maybe showing it inside of a DIV container etc.) but that's the idea.

Comment: in your demo it is working good, but when i apply it's not working. i edit the question plz check it.