# display all image the same size regardless of its original size

Tags: php, html, css, image

I have a table for member. When i display all image in html I put  and all of them are displayed with the same size but when I put class='img-responsive' they go back to their original size.

[image]

Comment: Did you check the answers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I now understand what you were asking. So let me explain.

All images have something called an **aspect ratio**. This can be **1:1** which means for every 1px(or whatever your unit of measurement is) there is 1px on the other side. Then 1:2 so for every 1px there is 2px on the other side and 1:3, 1:4 ...etc.

The ratio you would like to have is a 1:1 ratio that is 100px * 100px.

But this cannot be forced from an image with another aspect ratio without distorting the image. Companies like facebook do this by either creating cropped versions of the image or giving it a background-size of **cover**.

My recommendation would be to create a div with a height and width of 100px and set the image as a background image as follows:

```
.divClass{
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      background-size:cover;
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
}
```

Next add the following to your php code

```
<div class="divClass" style="background-image:url('image/location/<?php echo $imageName; ?>');">
```

This would allow the image to fill the div fully while keeping the aspect ratio. The downsides would be that some of the image would not be visible if the aspect ratio of the image is not 1:1 which is what you are trying to achieve. Also if you would like to change the position of the image you can use the background-position Property.

If you would like to be able to see the entire image you can add a popup box.

[jQuery: How can I show an image popup onclick of the thumbnail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063199/jquery-how-can-i-show-an-image-popup-onclick-of-the-thumbnail)

Your final solution would be to crop the images or allow the user to crop the image before they upload. Below is a great plugin that allow this.

https://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropperjs/

Comment: Sir the picture is generated from the database using php. So i put the background image inline with the div but it doesnt work. Even pasting your code. It just make the div 100x100 and the picture doesnt occupy the whole div

Comment: Okay sir. Can you give me 2 days before I mark your answer correct? I need to study this plugin thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force the width/height of the `img` element you can use :

```
img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

In case you are using some other libraries that override default css behavior you can use `!important`:

```
img {
    width: 100px !important;
    height: 100px !important;
}
```

The `img-responsive` class from bootstrap will set:

```
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

To the image, and if you want a specific width/height - this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: Nope. what i mean is if the image original size is 258x158 i want to display it 100x100. All of the image in my database regardless of their original size will be display 100x100 and will be responsive. Is that not possible?

Comment: If they will be displayed 100X100 - they are **not** responsive anymore, they are fixed. You should decide which of them you want. And yes - my answer will set all images to the exact width/height that you want.

Comment: Sir I give up on this one. I can't find solution that will make it 100x100 fixed and at the same time responsive. huhu if no other solution then i will marked this one correct

Comment: Can you please explain what do you mean by "100X100 fixed and **at the same time** responsive"? Maybe if I will understand what you mean by that I will be able to give a better solution. You can also try with example (I have an image of X*Y and i want to it be 100*100, I have an image of T*Z and i want to to be 20*20).

Comment: Cause i want the images from database displayed with the same height and width so it look nice regardless of their original size. Example 240x150 will be displayed 100x100. 320x200 will also be displayed 100x100. I also want them to be responsive using bootstrap 3 class img-responsive.
`<td><div><img src=" . $row['product_image'] . " width='100' height='100' class='img-responsive'></div></td>`

Comment: what do you mean by "I also want them responsive"? What is the actual outcome of that?

Comment: If i resize the browser the image is also scaling. Thats what img-responsive of bootstrap doing right

Comment: The problem you have is that you need to decide what will be the final solution - do you want the size to be **all the time** 100X100? or you want it to be responsive?

Comment: Lets say you have image which is 500X250 - what do you want the size to be? If it's 100X100 - it's **not** responsive. If it's 100X50 - it's responsive, but its **not** 100X100. So what would it be?